# Add class dynamically for react object (when dragged)

Tags: reactjs, draggable

I want to keep the dragged object on the top of other objects.

So,

I have css `basic.module.css`

```
.dragging-shelf {
  z-index:100;
}
```

then in function

```
import styles from "../css/basic.module.css";

const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false)
const handleStart = (e,data) =>{
    console.log("drag before:",data.node.classList);
    data.node.classList.add("dragging-shelf");
    console.log("drag after:",data.node.classList); 
    setIsDragging(true);
}
const handleStop = (e,data) =>{
    console.log("drag handle stop e:",e);
    console.log("drag handle stop data::",data);
    data.node.classList.remove("dragging-shelf");
    setIsDragging(false);
}

 return <Draggable onStart={handleStart} onDrag={handleDrag} onStop={handleStop}>   
         <div className='handle'>
          <MyObj></MyObj></div>
         </Draggable>
```

I can confirm `dragging-shelf` is added to `data.node.classList` with `console.log`.

However this is not reflected on browser.

My Dragged obj is behind another objs.

Comment: Its likely react isn't re-rendering the component tree.  You could try create a boolean useState `[dragging, setDragging]`.  Set it to true on handleStart and false on handleStop - After you have set the data.node.classlist though.  See if that now applies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added setDragging but still not changed.

Comment: What is your `data` in this line `data.node.classList.remove("dragging-shelf")`? Is it your `<MyObj />` or `<Draggable />`?

Comment: @haptn data is this div `<div className='handle'/>` ,, so maybe I should add the z-index to `<MyObj />`? however how can I do this? this is not DOM object this is React Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ReactJS`, whenever you want to make a list of classes dynamically, you can use libraries such as [`clsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) or [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).

As Vayne mentioned in the comment above, in your case, you can create a boolean useState to store your dragging status, then pass it in `clsx` or `classnames` as a condition. As a result of re-rendering, your component always has expected classes.

Example:

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
import styles from '../css/basic.module.css';

function DragComponnets() {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false)

  const handleStart = (e,data) => {
    setIsDragging(true);
  }
  const handleStop = (e,data) => {
    setIsDragging(false);
  }

  return (
    <Draggable onStart={handleStart} onDrag={handleDrag} onStop={handleStop}>   
      <div className={clsx('handle', {
        'dragging-shelf': isDragging
      )}>
          <MyObj></MyObj>
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  )
}
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The imperatively toggled css class is probably removed when the call to `setIsDragging` causes a re-render. Set the class declaratively instead:

```
...
return (
  <Draggable className={isDragging ? 'dragging-shelf' : ''} ...>   
    ...
  </Draggable>
)
```